# How to combine unknown number of data frames in R?

Tags: r

## Data

I have a data frame `df`. Following is a sample:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(-1,7,8), each=3), LV.vel.fps = 40:48, frames = 1:9)
```

And there are unknown number of other data frames, each with the prefix "comb." followed by a number. Each of these data frames represent data for a vehicle. Following data frame contains names of those vehicles (These numbers change based on the experiment so, there are 2 vehicles now but after another experiment there could be 9):

```
> ADO.names
       name
1 TrucPropk
2     Truck
```

So, `nrow(ADO.names)` tells us how many data frames there are. Following are the "comb." data frames for this particular example:

```
comb.1 <- data.frame(frames = 4:6, ADO.name = "TrucPropk", speed.fps = 43:45)
comb.2 <- data.frame(frames = 7:9, ADO.name = "Truck", speed.fps = 46:48)
```

Also, these data frames could have different number of rows.

## What I want to do

The "ID" variable in `df` contains the IDs of the vehicles in the "comb." data frames. -1 means no vehicle. The IDs are not available in the "comb." data frames but I want to add a new column "final.name" in `df` that contains the name of the vehicle for a given ID. This can be done by matching "speed.fps" from "comb." to "LV.vel.fps" in `df` because both are speeds in feet per second.
Therefore, the final output should look like this:

```
> df
  ID LV.vel.fps frames final.name
1 -1         40      1         NA
2 -1         41      2         NA
3 -1         42      3         NA
4  7         43      4  TrucPropk
5  7         44      5  TrucPropk
6  7         45      6  TrucPropk
7  8         46      7      Truck
8  8         47      8      Truck
9  8         48      9      Truck
```

## Problems

For these sample data frames, I could do following for joining data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  left_join(x = ., y = comb.1, by = "frames") %>% 
  left_join(x = ., y = comb.2, by = "frames")
```

And `ifelse` for "final.name":

```
df$final.name <- ifelse(df$speed.fps.x==df$LV.vel.fps,
                        df$ADO.name.x,
                        ifelse(df$speed.fps.y==df$LV.vel.fps,
                               df$ADO.name.y, "NA"))
```

But the output I get is wrong:

```
> df
  ID LV.vel.fps frames final.name ADO.name.x speed.fps.x ADO.name.y speed.fps.y
1 -1         40      1         NA       <NA>          NA       <NA>          NA
2 -1         41      2         NA       <NA>          NA       <NA>          NA
3 -1         42      3         NA       <NA>          NA       <NA>          NA
4  7         43      4          1  TrucPropk          43       <NA>          NA
5  7         44      5          1  TrucPropk          44       <NA>          NA
6  7         45      6          1  TrucPropk          45       <NA>          NA
7  8         46      7         NA       <NA>          NA      Truck          46
8  8         47      8         NA       <NA>          NA      Truck          47
9  8         48      9         NA       <NA>          NA      Truck          48
```

## Questions

So basically I have 2 questions:
1) How do I write code so that all "comb." data frames are joined with `df` regardless of number of those data frames? I knew there were 2 in this case so manually wrote "comb.1" and "comb.2" But the code should be robust for any number of data frames.
2) Why is my `ifelse` statement not generating correct output? How could I write robust code for this case as well?

Comment: Do you match just on "speed.fps" between `df` and `comb.n` or do you also match on `frames`?

Comment: I match on `frames`.

Comment: @akrun. It worked! The problem was that the number of decimal places in the 2 columns of speed were not same. I changed both to 2 and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much! I didn't know about `mget` and 'pattern`. Please include your answer again.

Comment: Just a doubt, are you using the edited code in the comment or the original one?

Comment: The code in the comment works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get the data.frame object names that starts with `comb` in a `list` using `mget`, `rbind` the `list` elements and then `merge` with the dataset 'df'.

```
res <- merge(df, do.call(rbind,
           mget(ls(pattern='^comb\\.\\d+')))[1:2], by='frames', all.x=TRUE)
colnames(res)[4] <- 'final.name'
res
# frames ID LV.vel.fps final.name
#1      1 -1         40       <NA>
#2      2 -1         41       <NA>
#3      3 -1         42       <NA>
#4      4  7         43  TrucPropk
#5      5  7         44  TrucPropk
#6      6  7         45  TrucPropk
#7      7  8         46      Truck
#8      8  8         47      Truck
#9      9  8         48      Truck
```

EDIT: As the OP mentioned about matching the 'speed' columns, we can include that also in the `merge`

```
res <- merge(df, 
       do.call(rbind,mget(ls(pattern='^comb\\.\\d+'))), 
          by.x=c('frames', 'LV.vel.fps'), by.y= c('frames', 'speed.fps'), 
            all.x=TRUE)
colnames(res)[4] <- 'final.name'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your code can merge the data frames but it is not matching the speeds while merging. The `frames` can be common for all "comb." data frames. I want to merge where the speeds match for a given `frames`. For my original data, this code gives following error: `Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`

Comment: @umairdurrani Perhaps `res <-  merge(df,  do.call(rbind,mget(ls(pattern='^comb\\.\\d+'))), by.x=c('frames', 'LV.vel.fps'), by.y= c('frames', 'speed.fps'), all.x=TRUE)`